# Haskell: Using 'map' within function to send all elements of a list to zero bar one

Tags: haskell

So I am defining a function that maps values to a 1 or 0 depending on whether there is a match or not.

For instance:

```
    match 3 [1,2,3,4,5] == [0,0,1,0,0]
```

What I have written so far for defining my 'match' function is:

```
    let match :: a -> [a] -> [Int]; match x xs = map
```

And of course I haven't finished writing it out after 'map' and this is what I need help on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`match x = map (fromEnum . (==x))`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I write 

        let match :: a -> [a] -> [Int]; match x = map (fromEnum . (==x))

And I get the error code

        Not instance for (Eq a) arising from use of '=='

Comment: @user3482534 - Your type signature should be `match :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this some kind of more straightforward version:

```
match e xs = map (\x -> if x == e then 1 else 0) xs
```